# Robot class without focus on browser window in WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, focus, selenium-chromedriver, awtrobot

I use `Selenium WebDriver` with `java.awt.Robot` class to handle dialog window, file picker during file upload process. I use `Chromedriver` to handle browser. If focus isn't on browser window, `Robot` pastes text to actual active field instead of browser window.
I can't send files directly to this input field without opening of a dialog window.

Comment: use AutoIT for this scenario,robot class is highly unstable and not recommended in automation.

Comment: @cruisepandey : I tried AutoIT, but it needs focus, dialog window is opened during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right xou want to send commands to your browser after opening a file chooser dialog?

To solve this, you can get the window handle of the browser

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindwoHandles();
```

After that you use

```
sriver.switchTo().window(windowHandleOfYourBrowser);
```

to Switch to your Chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, I want to send string to dialog window, when it is opened. Not sure, where should I put this code.

Comment: You place it when your dialog is open. Bit if you want to switch to a Dialog the code may differ a little bit. Then you have to say driver.switchTo().activeElement();

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help, if I click on the other browser window or somewhere else when dialog window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I hope `java.awt.Robot` cannot control the `Selenium WebDriver`. Weather the browser is in focus or not `java.awt.Robot` executes it's action.

In your case , you can bring the browser focus on and call your robot methods.

Before robot class methods...

```
//Get back the focus 
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

//Robot class methods...

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this, but it hasn't any effect during execution.